# How to stroke and reveal a path slowly?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, drawing, core-animation

For a scientific simulation, I need to  stroke and reveal a path slowly over time, starting at the first point and traveling through all other points until reaching the last point. Like if you take a pencil and start slowly drawing a circle, spiral or triangle.

How could I do this with Core Animation or maybe OpenGL ES? Core Graphics would possibly be too slow to refresh at 60 fps.

There is CAKeyframeAnimation which can travel along a path, but I need a way of actually stroking that path while traveling along it.

Edit: Should run on iOS 3.2 as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a `CAShapeLayer` to display your path.
2. Animate the layer's `strokeEnd` property from `0.0` to `1.0`.

See [this blog post of mine](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/) for details.